# cursor.fetchall() returns an empty list sometimes

Tags: python, sqlite

I've been learning python/sqlite from a tutorial am just mucking around and trying out some extra stuff. I've found that if I print cursor.fetchall() I get what I expect (a list containing a tuple), but if I try to use it (e.g. return it as in the example below, or if I try to unpack it (e.g. `emp = c.fetchall()`), it just returns an empty list.

```
import sqlite3
from employee import Employee # class with first, last and pay attributes

def insert_emp(emp):
    with connection:
        c.execute("INSERT INTO employees VALUES (:first, :last, :pay)", 
                {'first':emp.first, 'last':emp.last, 'pay':emp.pay})

def get_emps_by_name(lastname):
    c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM employees WHERE last=? ", (lastname,))
    print(c.fetchall()) # - for testing, prints out fine
    return c.fetchall() # - why doesn't this work?


connection = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

c = connection.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employees (
    first TEXT,
    last TEXT,
    pay INTEGER
    )""")

if input("Would you like to add a record? (y/n)\n\n...") == 'y':
    emp = Employee(input('Enter firstname: '), input('Enter last name: '), input('Enter salary: '))
    insert_emp(emp)

print(get_emps_by_name(input('Enter last name to search: ')))
```

Output:

```
Would you like to add a record? (y/n)


...y 
Enter firstname: John 
Enter last name: Doe Enter salary: 50000 
Enter last name to search: Doe 
[('John', 'Doe', 50000)]
[]
```

I'm just wondering why this happens?

Thanks!

Comment: you have to commit every time you use it because it will get exhaust. First time it will fetch you everything but in the next use there will be nothing left so you have to run the query again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because you are calling "fetchall" twice. The first instance will display the actual value, but when call the second time will call the next set of values. Thus, returning an empty value (since there is nothing else).

Comment: Then what to do? Do you need to make it start over so its the First time again?